# kind level identity in haskell

Tags: haskell, type-families

Is it possible to construct a kind level identity which maps a kind `a` to the same kind `a` in haskell ?

Here are some non-answers :

```hs
type One :: * -> *
newtype One a = One {unOne :: a}

-- >>> :kind! 'One
-- 'One :: a -> One a -- not the identity
-- = 'One
```

```hs
type family Id a where -- *pointwise* identity, not a function (can't not apply it)
  Id a = a
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently the type language is *first-order*, meaning unmatchable functions like `Id` must be fully saturated: [*Higher-Order Type-Level Programming in Haskell*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2019/03/unsaturated-type-families-icfp-2019.pdf).

A proposal has been accepted to remedy this: [*Unsaturated type families*](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/242).

Under this proposal we distinguish between the kind of `One :: Type -> Type` and `Id :: k -> k`; `One` is matchable and `Id` is unmatchable:

```hs
One :: Type -> @M Type
Id  :: k    -> @U k
```

and we will be able to pass unmatchable type-level functions as arguments:

```hs
data Foo :: (Type -> @U Type) -> Type
data Foo f = MkFoo (f Int) (f Bool) (f Char)

foo :: Foo Id
foo = MkFoo 10 False 'a'
```

This will allow you to construct proper identity functors, functor composition and categorical gadgets.

```hs
type  Functor :: (s -> @m t) -> Constraint
class (Category (Source f), Category (Target f))
   => Functor (f :: s -> @m t) where
  type Source (f :: s -> @m t) :: Cat s
  type Target (f :: s -> @m t) :: Cat t

  fmap :: Source f a a' -> Target f (f a) (f a')

type IdFunctor :: Cat ob -> ob -> ob
type IdFunctor cat a = a

instance Category @ob cat => Functor (IdFunctor @ob cat) where
  type Source (IdFunctor cat) = cat
  type Target (IdFunctor cat) = cat

  fmap :: cat a a' -> cat a a'
  fmap = id
```

Comment: I really wish it was here, as many people do, I imagine.

Comment: I wish so too, it would "unblock" various categorical issues such as getting a category of categories which requires a proper identity functor (for `id`) and a proper composition of functors (for `(.)`). With [first-class existentials](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/473) we can give it the kind `Cat (exists ob. Cat ob)` but getting `Category` instantiated at such a type is a different matter.

Comment: Pretty important stuff. Ideally one might want to define 2-Cat's, and Cat as being one of those (I call the category of categories `1-Cat` to not be confused fwiw). The proposal seems linked to a few others ([syntax modifiers](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/370), maybe [visible forall](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0281-visible-forall.rst)), so this might not be happen anytime soon (?).  I imagine the situation is better with OCaml's modules.